# Find the number of files in a Sonar Project using Sonar Rest Api?

Tags: sonarqube

I want to find the number of files in a sonar Project project.

I use the following Url format to get the data.

http://sonarUrl/sonar/api/resources?resource=sonarProjname&depth=-1&scopes=FIL.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

*api/resources* is deprecated. But:

- the number of files is a built-in metric that gets computed for any project ( [example](https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures/domain/Size?id=drupal) ). Key of that metric is *files*.
- measures can be obtained via the WebAPI (documentation embedded in your own SonarQube server), using *api/measures/component*.

So just call that API with the appropriate *metricKeys* and *componentKey*  and you'll be good to go ([example](https://sonarcloud.io/api/measures/component?metricKeys=files&componentKey=drupal)).